# Add variable to row of an array

Tags: arrays, typescript, ionic-framework, controller, row

I am trying to get data from back office and verify if it exists into another table so I add a value called 'validation' for each row of the array which contains the result of verification. The problem is each time it adds the value to an other row into the array, but I want to add it into the row

Details:

```
testobj() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.listObj.length; i++) {
        console.log(this.listObj[i].id_obj_ser);
        this.etudiant.getobjectifvalidation(this.listObj[i].id_obj_ser, this.cin).subscribe((data: any) => {
            if (data.length != 0) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log('i = ' + i);
                this.listObj[i].push({'validation': data[i-1].validation});
                console.log(this.listObj[i]);
            }
        });
        }
        console.log(this.listObj);
}
```

listObj : array al ready exist

this.listObj[i].push: this is the new value I want to add it into the row and not to the array.

Comment: instead of pushing you can do `this.listObj[i].validation = data[i-1].validation`

Comment: the column validation doesn't exist int the listObj but i want to add it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pushing to an object (an item within `this.listObj`), you can simply just add the new field by doing

`this.listObj[i].field_name = value`

**NB**: [push() is for arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), not [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Methods),

Check the example code below and check your console

```js
var listObject = [
{id: 1, name:'item name'},
{id: 2, name: 'item name2'},
{id: 3, name: 'item name 3'}
]

console.log('original object', listObject)

for(var i=0; i<listObject.length; i++){

// i can manipulate each item here
// if the item is even validate should be true
listObject[i].validate = true
}

console.log('new object', listObject)
```

Check your console and see how the items were altered for objects